# After importing tables from DB2 they do not show up on the relational model or anywhere in the design?

Tags: import, db2, oracle-sql-data-modeler, relational-model

I'm trying to reverse engineer a data warehouse that is on DB2 into Oracle Data Modeler. When I choose to import from data dictionary I can view the schemas and tables but after I select the needed ones they do not show up in the relational model. I found the following errors in the logging page:

- MOHStorageGroupDB2.extract(): DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SYSIBM.SYSSTOGROUP, DRIVER=4.21.29
- MOHTablespaceDB2.extract(): DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SYSIBM.SYSTABLESPACE, DRIVER=4.21.29
- MOHDatabaseDB2.extract(): DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SYSIBM.SYSDATABASE, DRIVER=4.21.29
- MOHSequenceDB2v80.extract(): DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=SCHEMA, DRIVER=4.21.29
- MOHProcedureDB2v80.extract(): DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=SCHEMA, DRIVER=4.21.29
- MOHTableDB2v80.generate(): DATAWAREHOUSE.DIMSTUDENTLEVEL
- null at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbEditorContainer.getURL (NbEditorContainer.java:1019)

Comment: What’s your DB2 database platform and version?

Comment: Cloud DB2 v11.1.9.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Oracle Data Modeler tries to access DB2 for Z/OS specific system catalog tables like [`SYSIBM.SYSDATABASE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/cattab/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsysdatabasetable.html), which are not available in Db2 for LUW databases.

These are different products. So, you should make your tool work with namely the Db2 for LUW product.

BTW,
You do see the system catalog tables in the `SYSIBM` schema in Db2 for LUW (like `SYSIBM.SYSTABLESPACES`, but not `SYSIBM.SYSTABLESPACE` as in DB2 for Z/OS), but it's always advisable to use system catalog **views** in the `SYSCAT` schema based on tables in the `SYSIBM` schema, instead of using `SYSIBM` tables directrly in Db2 for LUW.

Comment: Thank you, I used UDB connection instead of DB2 and it worked.